# What do the suffixes on stock symbols indicate

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy, terminology, warrants

For example, [this](http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/10/26/us-internet-probe-new-york-idUSKCN0SK0AH20151026) article mentions symbols `VZ.N`, `CVC.N`, `TWC.N`, and `CCOI.O`.

Are these related to share classes and/or warrants?  Each of these symbols also seem to exist and can be referenced without the suffix.

I don't see those particular suffixes in this [table](https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=CQSSymbolConvention)

I notice that on the stock pages (i.e. [CVC.N](http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=CVC.N)) the stats vary between the suffixed (`CVC.N`) and non-suffixed (`CVC`) versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The suffix represents the stock exchange the stock is traded on. N represents the New York Stock Exchange and O represents the Nasdaq.

Sometimes a stock can be listed on more than one exchange so the suffix will give you an indication of which exchange the stock is on. For example the Australian company BHP Billiton Ltd is listed on multiple exchanges so is given a different suffix for the different exchanges (especially when the code is the same for each exchange). Below are a few examples of BHP:

- BHP.AX - Australian Stock Exchange
- BHP.BA - Buenos Aires
- BHP.SG - Stuttgart
- BHP.F - Frankfurt
- BHP - NYSE
- BHP.DU - Dusseldorf

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Is this a standardized notation and is there a place to map suffixes to exchanges? I notice that in your example `BHP` maps to NYSE despite the lack of `.N` suffix.  Would `BHP.N` also be correct or is it common to omit the suffix given some idea of a "default" exchange?

Comment: It is because BHP is listed as an American Depositary Receipt (ADR). Shares of many non-U.S. companies trade on U.S. stock exchanges through ADRs, which are denominated and pay dividends in U.S. dollars and may be traded like regular shares of stock.[